# Add data to sql on button click

Tags: php, html, function, button, qsqlquery

my page receives data which i retrieve with $_post. I display some data and at the bottom of page my button has to save data to mysql. I could submit form to next page, but how do i access the data that I have retrieved with post then? Lets say i have following code (in reality alot more variables ..):

```
<?php
$v= $_POST["something"];
echo $v;
echo "Is the following information correct? //this would be at the bottom of the page with the buttons
?>
<input type="button" value="submit data" name="addtosql">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two methods:

1) You can save the `POST` variable in a `hidden` field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="somevalue" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["something"])) echo $_POST["something"];?>" >
```

The hidden value also will get passed to the action page on `FORM` submission. In that page you can access this value using

```
echo $_POST['somevalue'];
```

2) Use `SESSION`

You can store the value in `SESSION` and can access in any other page.

```
$v= $_POST["something"];
session_start();
$_SESSION['somevalue']=$v;
```

and in next page access `SESSION` variable using,

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['somevalue']))
   echo $_SESSION['somevalue'];
```

Comment: i have like 100 variables to save. Is there any better way?

Comment: @Newb..No then use SESSIONS

Comment: is it possible to create temp table with all data and then on next page tranfer it to real table?

Comment: @Newb..That is not a good method. Better way is to save it as SESSION.

Comment: Thanks made it :D seassions are the most optimal solution afterall

Answer (score 0):

Take a look. Below every thing should be on single php page

```
  // first create a function

     function getValue($key){
        if(isset($_POST[$key]))
            return $_POST[$key];
        else
           return "";
   }


   // process your form here
       if(isset($_POST['first_name']){
         // do your sql stuff here.
      }

 // now in html 

   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="text"  name="first_name"  value="<?php echo getValue("first_name"); ?>" />
         <input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but i have like 100 variables. I cant do this for each one